# Slider in div only works outside div

Tags: javascript, html, css, label, containers

I have a slider that is designed inside of a div. That div is placed inside a label tag.

The slider does not slide when the div (or slider itself) is clicked, only when the outside container which I believe to be the label is clicked. I can click in every single place EXCEPT the div/slider.

Here is a demo of the issue: https://www.loom.com/share/82adc2fd640e45d1ad3f38dfa356faa0

Here is the code for the slider:

```
  <label class="switch" for="checkbox">
            <input name="rep-management" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
            <div class="slider round"></div>
          </label>
        </label>
```

Comment: Please share full code, this snippet is not enough to understand.

Comment: Please first correct your HTML. A div is not allowed inside a label element.